# What is a "factor" in factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis, terminology, linear-algebra, definition

What is a factor from a linear algebra point of view?  Is it a vector, matrix, basis, tuple, coordinate system or something else?

Comment: What is your current knowledge about it from student point of view?

Comment: ttnphns, vector?

Answer (score 4):

The usual factor analysis model is

$$\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{\mu}+ \mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{L} + \mathbf{\eta},$$

where $\mathbf{Y}$ represents a collection of $n$ observations of $k$ random variables; i.e. it is a matrix of $n \times k$ size. $\mathbf{\mu} = \mathbf{1}_n^{\prime} (\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_k)$
   is also an $n\times k$ matrix, constant in each column, giving the
   means of the $k$ variables. $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is a $n\times p$ matrix of $p \le k$ factors; $\mathbf{L}$ is an $p \times n$ matrix of (unknown) *constants* (to be estimated); and $\mathbf{\eta}$ is an $n \times k$ matrix of errors.  The rows of $\mathbf{\eta}$ are independent and independent of $\Phi$. The elements within row $i$ have mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$.  The quantities on the right hand side are unobservable but (usually) fewer in number than the $nk$ data values, and so are (up to a degree of ambiguity discussed below) *identifiable*. Note that $\eta$ is not to be identified, but only its row variances $\sigma_i^2$, called "uniquenesses".

In the language of factor analysis, the *factors* are the columns of $\mathbf{\Phi}$. From $k$ original variables it extracts $p\lt k$ factors. One can say that a "factor" is a whole column; i.e., a collection of $n$ realizations of a random variable, or, more abstractly, a random variable itself.  Usually it is assumed that the factors are uncorrelated and standardized, i.e. have unit variance.

The rows of $\mathbf{L}$ are called *factor loadings*.

Note that this model is unique only up to orthogonal transformations, in that 
$$\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{\mu}+ (\mathbf{\Phi P^\top})(\mathbf{PL}) + \mathbf{\eta},$$
where $\mathbf{P}$ is any orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @whuber: Well, let's consider it accurately. Of course I agree that matrix $Y$ can be defined to be $n\times k$. So this answer says that $L$ are factor loadings and is $n\times k$ and $\Phi$ are factors and is $k\times k$. Can you show me in wikipedia what this corresponds to? Wikipedia calls data matrix $Z$ and it's the same size as $Y$. Good. Then it says that it's equal to $LF$ (up to the noise and a constant), where loadings $L$ are $n\times p$ and $F$ is $p \times k$. Do you see the difference? Of course $F=\Phi$ cannot be either square or diagonal, as claimed by Dennis.

Comment: @whuber: It seems that in my first comment I introduced some more confusion, so I have erased it now. Given that Dennis did not appear here from September, I am wondering if we should edit his answer to become correct. It seems to be easy to do.

Comment: @amoeba You're right.  Comparing this to Wikipedia is confusing because of how it transposes the usual (cases $\times$ variables) array, but a close inspection indicates this answer is not in agreement.  To be fair to you, why don't we reverse our roles? I'll try to fix up the answer and you can provide helpful criticism :-).

Comment: @whuber: Sure, go ahead! I will comment after you edit.

Comment: @amoeba I tried but I could not rescue it (which was an educational exercise for me).  The effort ultimately foundered because really $\mathbf{Y}$ ought to be conceived of as a *realization* of $n$ vector-valued random variables, not as an $n\times p$ random variable. By taking the point of view introduced in this answer we lose the ability to describe the relationships among the rows of $\mathbf Y$ in any simple or succinct manner.  I think I will abandon the attempt to fix this answer up.

Comment: @whuber: Are you referring to the unortunate wording "(matrix-valued)random variable"? I believe it is simply a negligent mistake, not a real belief of Dennis. So to fix the answer, one should edit a bit more than you were probably ready to do. I will now attempt to do it, and if you think that it's too much, you will be able to roll back as a mod.

Comment: @whuber: Done and upvoted. Can you please take a careful look?

Comment: @Amoeba I added some important assumptions that had been omitted. At the end I directly answered the question.

Comment: @whuber: I am happy with all edits up to the last paragraph, but am confused about that one. Don't we say above that "factors" are not basis vectors in $\mathbb R^k$ (these are proportional to "factor loadings"), but rather transformed variables?

Comment: @whuber: In addition to my previous comment: in fact, there is even more indeterminacy here, because we are not fitting the noise matrix $\eta$ (only its row variances are fitted in FA), so there is some freedom in what goes into $\eta$ and what goes into actual factors. This is why in the FA literature there are all these different methods of computing factor scores $\Phi$ once one found the loadings $L$ and uniquenesses $\sigma^2_i$. I think we should either remove the last two sentences (that you added), or think very carefully about how to modify them.

Answer (score -1):

Factor is a vector. The set of factors give you a coordinate system, a basis. Factor loadings are sets of coordinates in this basis.

Let's say you have a $T\times n$ matrix $X=x_{ti}$. Imagine that it's a path of particle in n-dimensional space, where $t$ is time, and $i$ is the dimension.

What factor analysis does is simply change the coordinate system from your current basis to something else, then your $X$ matrix becomes a $T\times n$ matrix $A=a_{ti}$. It's the same path in time, except in different coordinates. The actual coordinates of a point at time $t$ are called *loadings* or a score in PCA, i.e. each row is a particular point in time, a loading.

The reason to transform the coordinates is usually convenience or clarity. For instance, these would be coordinates of circular motion in cartesian system (x,y):

```
    0.8415    0.5403
    0.9093   -0.4161
    0.1411   -0.9900
   -0.7568   -0.6536
   -0.9589    0.2837
   -0.2794    0.9602
    0.6570    0.7539
    0.9894   -0.1455
    0.4121   -0.9111
   -0.5440   -0.8391
```

Here's the same in polar system (angle,radius):

```
1.0000    1.0000
2.0000    1.0000
3.0000    1.0000
4.0000    1.0000
5.0000    1.0000
6.0000    1.0000
0.7168    1.0000
1.7168    1.0000
2.7168    1.0000
3.7168    1.0000
```

The polar system is obviously suited better for this process, as you can shrink the dimensionality of the system. It's essentially one-dimensional motion along the circle's circumference.

Factor analysis is usually linear in some way, and doesn't do cool stuff like this, but still works for many processes.

Comment: Literally *anything* in mathematics can be considered a vector. Thus, to provide any meaningful information, you need to describe the *vector space* and what it represents. At least give us a clue as to its dimension!